# Select Edge Loop does not work

Tags: shortcut, navigation

To solve this, I disabled "Emulate 3 Button Mouse" in the preferences. The problem is, now I can not navigate in the viewport anymore. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>, nothing moves. I appreciate your help!

Comment: what about the Middle Mouse Button?

Comment: If you only want to select one loop you don't need the Shift key. Just ALT-Left-Click will do, assuming left-click select (the default) is set in Preferences > Keymap. The Shift key is only needed to select more than one loop.

Answer (score 0):

When using "Emulate 3 Button Mouse", simply double left clicking an edge will result in an edge loop selection. For ring selections, click on a starting edge, and control + double left clicking will initiate the ring select.

Note: *The mouse cursor position on the mesh can influence ring selections*. If a horizontal edge is initially selected and your mouse cursor is closer to a vertical edge, the vertical edge ring will become selected instead.